# Octobercms: how to add 'styles' and 'scripts' placeholders to combined assets?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

How do I add `{% styles %}` and `{% scripts %}` to the combined assets array in October CMS?

Comment: seems its not possible right now[https://octobercms.com/forum/post/combine-injected-assets] but you can add Feature request to October cms repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems its not possible right now.

> https://octobercms.com/forum/post/combine-injected-assets

but you can add Feature request to October cms repository.

> https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues

add it as `Feature request / Conceptual Enhancement`